# How can I use apt-get to list all packages written in C?

Tags: command-line, apt, c

Is there any way I can use apt-get to give me a list of all packages written in C, or that have C modules in them?

Answer (score 12):

The [debtags](http://packages.ubuntu.com/debtags) [image: Install debtags] package could be useful for this.

`debtags search devel::lang:c`

This will list all packages which have been tagged as written in C.

`apt-cache rdepends libc6` will show you all packages that depend on libc6.